# React how to memoize a component that receives a very nested object/array as prop

Tags: reactjs, memoization, memo

`React.memo` uses a shallow comparison to determine if the props are equal, but I need to pass an object or array as prop, so I went into an `areEqual` condition, but the `currentProps` and `nextProps` values are always the same. I mean, the component does not render.

Lets say this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      name: "First name",
      amount: 0
    },
    {
      name: "Other name",
      amount: 0
    }
  ]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type in for test"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <br />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Click to increment first!"
        onClick={() => {
          const temp = [...data];
          temp[0].amount += 1;
          setData(temp);
        }}
      />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Click to increment other!"
        onClick={() => {
          const temp = [...data];
          temp[1].amount += 1;
          setData(temp);
        }}
      />
      <br />

      <Child data={data} />
    </>
  );
}
```

and

```
const Child = ({ data }) => {
  const count = useRef(0);
  return (
    <>
      {data &&
        data.map((obj, index) => {
          return obj.name + "-" + obj.amount;
        })}
      <br />
      Count: {count.current++}
    </>
  );
};

const areEqual = (currentProps, nextProps) => {
  console.log(currentProps.data[0].amount, nextProps.data[0].amount);
  console.log(currentProps.data[1].amount, nextProps.data[1].amount);
  if (
    currentProps.data[0].amount === nextProps.data[0].amount &&
    currentProps.data[1].amount === nextProps.data[1].amount
  ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

export default memo(Child, areEqual);
```

but no matter what always currentProps and nextProps are returning the very same value:
[image]

Everything is on [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-morning-52nqw?file=/src/App.js). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the object mutation. Create a new object reference instead.

**Don't**

```js
const temp = [...data];
temp[0].amount += 1;
setData(temp);
```

**Do**

```js
setData(
  data.map((item, index) =>
    index === 0 ? { ...item, amount: item.amount + 1 } : item
  )
);
```

**Also works (using a temporary variable)**

If you prefer the mutation style of using a `temp` variable, you should avoid using the same object reference:

```js
const temp = [...data];
temp[0] = { ...temp[0], amount: temp[0].amount + 1 };
setData(temp);
```

**Why?**

> but no matter what always currentProps and nextProps are returning the very same value

`currentProps` and `nextProps` are different (the references of the `data` prop are different). You can check it by adding `console.log(currentProps.data === nextProps.data)` to your `areEquals` function (it will return `false`).

By reusing the same object references, when you make the mutation on one object (for instance the one at index 0) it gets updated in both `currentProps.data[0]` and `nextProps.data[0]`. You can check it by adding `console.log(currentProps.data[0] === nextProps.data[0])` to your `areEquals` function (it will return `true`).